# Вариативные шаблоны С++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

При попытке написания конструктора с вариативным шаблоном возникла проблема с получением значений переменных, переданных с помощью него. Как это можно осуществить? Заранее спасибо.

```
MyArray(const int size, const Values&... values) {
    a = new T[size];
    int counter = 0;
    while (counter != size) {
        a[counter++] = values;
    }
}
```

Comment: Что вы тут вообще пытаетесь сделать? Почему шаблона никакого не видно? Почему передаются какие-то `Values`, а запихивается все в массив из каких-то `T`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В общем случае аргументы могут иметь разный тип, поэтому обратиться к i-ому аргументу по номеру можно только если этот номер известен во время компиляции: `std::get<i>(std::tie(values...))`.

Но если уверены, что у аргументов одинаковый тип, то можно запихнуть их в массив: `T *array[] = {values...};` (массив указателей - чтобы избежать копирования), и дальше работать с ним как обычно.

Кстати, размер передавать отдельным параметром не нужно. Его можно получить так: `sizeof...(Values)` (или `values`, не важно).

Если не хочется засовывать аргументы в массив, то можно еще написать вот так:

```
template <typename ...Values>
MyArray(const Values&... values) {
    a = new T[sizeof...(Values)];
    int counter = 0;
    ((a[counter++] = values), ...);
}
```

Здесь `((a[counter++] = values), ...);` - это так называемое [*fold-expression*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold). Оно превращается в `(values[counter++] = values_1), (values[counter++] = values_2), ... ;`.

Или еще один вариант - вообще в одну строчку:

```
a = new T{values...};
```